# Graphing a tangent function with an amplitude

Tags: trigonometry

Because of the all real values for the range of a tangent graph, the amplitude seems to have no effect on the maximum or minimum of the graph, but to change its steepness. i just want to seek reassurance whether this is true or not?

Comment: $\tan(x)$ doesn’t have an amplitude like $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ do. Other than that, I’m not sure I understand your question.

Comment: It sounds like you’re talking about domains and ranges in some sense, but in my opinion your question needs clarification. Please be clearer/more explicit/give more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a coefficient in front of $\tan{x}$, you do not alter the asymptotes. So yes, all it will do is change the steepness. One way you could measure/observe this is the slope at $x=2πn$. But since it isn't a wave, I don't think amplitude is the right word.